# 404 when trying to access file which exists

Tags: iis-7.5, mime-types, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm having trouble while trying to access a file in the browser, it says "404 - file not found" but I know for a fact that the file does exist. I can only access it once and then when I refresh it's gone into 404 mode again.

When I delete the file, a different kind of 404 message appears then when the file exists. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

- Server OS: Windows Server 2008 R2
- IIS Version: 7.5
- Filename: loop.mp4

I did set the mime-type on the server for the .mp4 extension to video/mp4.

Comment: Sounds too vague for me... Try enable debugging in your web.config, it might give you more info about "how" is the file missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today someone hinted me to do some request tracing and look at the full status code, which was 404.3. That meant that I didn't have the correct mime map set on the server. I added the mime-type on server level instead of on site level and now it works like a charm. Thank you for trying to help me anyway :)